# Conditional labeling when substr condition is met R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
gg.genes <- ggplot(genes.to.plot, aes(genes.x, genes.to.plot$START)) +
    geom_text(size = 3,
              hjust = -0.2,
              vjust = 0,
              aes(label = ""),        
              color = 'black',
              data = subset(genes.to.plot, startsWith(genes.to.plot$GENE, "A")),
              aes(label = genes.to.plot$GENE)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend=genes.x, yend=genes.to.plot$STOP),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm"),
                               angle = 15),
                        colour = 'green4') +
    labs(x="", y = "") +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

So, i'm plotting the Strand information about certain genes. 
If you would like to recreate the data which I'm using to plot this, just do:

```
GENE START STOP STRAND
A    1     2    + 
B    2     4    -
AC   3     6    +
DA   4     8    -
```

What I'm struggling with is the selective labeling, but more particularly with `startsWith` and `subset`.

I want to only plot the labels for the genes that start with "A". In my case (A and AC)

But when I use starts with, I'm getting the error:

```
Error in startsWith(genes.to.plot$GENE, "A") : non-character object(s)
```

I don't understand this error because I'm feeding the correct info in the function

I'm very new to the R, and I'm expecting some downvotes but can you help me with this minor thing?

Comment: `genes.to.plot` is probably a factor: compare `startsWith('apple', 'a'); startsWith(factor('apple'), 'a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `genes.to.plot$GENE` is probably a *factor*. To avoid the error, ensure that the column type is `character` instead. For instance:

```
genes.to.plot$GENE = as.character(genes.to.plot$GENE)
```

Or, better yet, don’t make it into a factor in the first place. This probably happened automatically when creating your data.frame. Specify the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to avoid it.

Comment: `Error in as.vector(y) : attempt to apply non-function`     for this line `data = subset(genes.to.plot, startsWith(as.character(genes.to.plot$GENE), "A"))`

Comment: @Mixalis Hm, that exact code works for me. Make sure that the function `as.character` isn’t overridden in your R session.